# Adding text and password to a PDF using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

Suppose I have a PDF document on my server, and I want to add certain text (e.g., "This copy is licensed to John Doe and is for personal use only") at the bottom of each page, and then protect the resulting PDF document with a password, generated at run-time. All that is obviously for (a) identifying the copy of a PDF as downloaded by a certain user (who's name is going to be included in that footer I want to add and is, therefore, variable) and (b) adding some (I know, not much, but still) security with a password that is sent to the user separately.

So my question is: what would be the easiest way to accomplish those two tasks in a PHP script? Is it possible to do with free/open source libraries only?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) is able to encrypt the PDF. Check this: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php. In particular example #16 gives a nice example of protecting a pdf file and to add a custom header/footer.

Comment: I would agree, this seems to fit the bill perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that for the case when the PDF document is created on the fly? My case is different - I have a ready-made PDF, which needs to have a footer and a password added to it. Can that example be adopted to such a case? I have no experience with TCPDF myself, so asking might be the quickest way to find that out :)

Comment: Uhm... you're right. TCPDF can't load existing pdfs. But [this page](http://solaajayi.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/pdf-templates-using-tcpdf/) shows that it has been extended with FPDI, which can load them, then you can use TCPDF to add whatever. That link shows how to add a header to an existing file. I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP script will time out if the PDF is very big. Instead, you could offload the job to a OS-level service running on the server computer.